# filter first_name and last_name from two relation pointing to same table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am having columns `first_name` and `last_name` in `user` table, which in turn related to `order_item` table having `instructor_id` and `user_id` both id linked to `user` table.

now I am having relations defined in `OrderItem` Model like:

```
public function getInstructor() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'instructor_id']);
    }
```

and

```
public function getCustomerName() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
```

and in `OrderSearch` Model

```
public $instructor;
public $name;

$query->joinWith(['instructor','location1','customerName n']);        

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(user.first_name," ",user.last_name)',  $this->name]) 
        ->$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(user.first_name," ",user.last_name)',  $this->instructor]);
```

Now I am getting error like

```
Method yii\db\ActiveQuery::__toString() must not throw an exception, 
caught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

if I am removing the alias n in joinwith, I am getting error like:
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user'

```
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `order_item` LEFT JOIN `user` ON
`order_item`.`instructor_id` = `user`.`id` LEFT JOIN `location` ON `order_item`.`location_id` =  
`location`.`id` LEFT JOIN `user` ON `order_item`.`user_id` = `user`.`id`
```

Comment: I don't understand what it means to COUNT on OUTER JOINes tables

Comment: that query is being run by yii2 framework, I assume it first tries to find if it returns any result by using count..

Comment: @Strawberry - you have added the alias in the query, whereas I am getting that error when I am not using any alias.

Comment: There are two `LEFT JOIN user`, is it telling you that you need to alias one of them?

Comment: Oh - each time you call an instance of a table you need to give it a different alias

Comment: yes, if we can do alias with one, it should be okay. but when I am doing I am getting another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler then I was thinking, but took a lot of time to resolve.
but I am still not clear why the method in the question won't work.

like what I did, that I separated the query as below and used the alias in the query.

**existing**

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(user.first_name," ",user.last_name)',  $this->name]) 
->$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(user.first_name," ",user.last_name)',  $this->instructor]);
```

**updated**

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(n.first_name," ",n.last_name)',  $this->name]); 
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(user.first_name," ",user.last_name)',  $this->instructor]);
```

and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make it similar to this:

```
class Order {
...
  //first relation with table COMPANY
  public function getCustomer()
  {
      return $this->hasOne( Company::className(), ['id' => 'customerid'] ) //table COMPANY
                  ->andOnCondition( [ '==relationAlias==.type' => 'customer' ] );
  }

  //second relation with table COMPANY
  public function getSupplier()
  {
      return $this->hasOne( Company::className(), ['id' => 'supplierid'] ) //table COMPANY
                  ->andOnCondition( [ '==relationAlias==.type' => 'supplier' ] );
  }
...
}
```

Then we could write

```
$orders = Order::find()
                   ->alias( 'o' )
                   ->innerJoinWith('customer c')
                   ->innerJoinWith('supplier s');
```

To build query

```
select o.* from order o
join company c on c.id = o.customerid and c.type = 'customer'
join company s on s.id = o.supplierid and s.type = 'supplier'
```

This question was asked at github with presented solution:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10883